# use keycode in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, keycode

After wrestling through a large amount of Bash / Linux Threads and Docs I ended up here a little bit desperated.

I want to add a new Block to my i3bar but I'm not an experienced Shell Scripter.

My script should continue the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
cv =" read value out of /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/actual_brightness"
if [[ keycode 224 or keycode 225 are pressed ]]; then
  switch $cv
    case $cv =/ ( 0 && 4427 ) then
      if [[ Keycode 225 is pressed ]]; then
        echo  $cv + 227 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
      elif [[ Keycode 224 is pressed ]]; then
        echo  $cv - 227 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
      fi
    case $cv = 0 then
      if [[ Keycode 225 is pressed ]]; then
        echo  $cv + 227 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
      elif [[ Keycode 224 is pressed ]]; then
        break;
    case $cv = 4437 then    
      if [[ Keycode 224 is pressed ]]; then
        echo  $cv - 227 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
      elif [[ Keycode 225 is pressed ]]; then
        break;
      fi
fi
```

This script will be called by i3blocks, which isn't a problem.
I just can't figure out how to "call" this keypress events.

Furthermore I found the max brightness value by reading the 
/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/max_brightness file and would love to know, if there is another possible way ( without another helpertool ) to get this value.

I'm thankful for every recommendation. 
I'm using sway and wayland ( I'm a newbie, not sure if this information is necessary).

Comment: The script is not written in bash. So, if you are new to something, don't hesitate and learn it. There is no point in writing here what is explained in endless bash tutorials on the net. Also the tag [keycode] is something from javascript, is it relevant here? If you intent to write on this forum, please take your time to read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @dogma : I suggest that you first fix the syntax errors (for instance using [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)). It doesn't take much sense to talk about the logic of a program, which is not even syntactically correct. Alternatively (if you are not interested in dealing with syntax issues right now), ask a new question which focuses on only the problem with the keycodes, because I don't quite understand what you are wanting to do.